# Laravel with ioncube and encoding

Tags: php, laravel, encoding, ioncube

I work on Laravel framework for a short time, after finishing the website, I willing to encode it using Ioncube - but I face the problem where Ioncube can't translate the blade template engine code to PHP code before encoding and output the code as HTML normal text.

Comment: can you explain how you managed to encode your Laravel controllers? I'm having issues encoding mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846509/encoding-laravel-with-ioncube

Answer (score 6):

Laravel's blade template files are not real PHP code, therefore the ionCube Encoder cannot encode them properly; however, the Encoder also offers file encryption which might help in your case, but it does require a bit of a setup:

1. In Laravel, modify the module that reads in the Blade template files, replacing `file_get_contents(<blade template files>)` with `ioncube_read_file(<blade template_files>)`.

   In my Laravel 4 installation, it seems like the file responsible for loading and compiling Blade Templates can be found in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php`, line 62: `$contents = $this->compileString($this->files->get($path));`.

   Here, `$this->files->get($path)` is 'just' a `file_get_contents($path)` with some error handling - you may find this function in `bootstrap/compiled.php`. However, you should be able to replace the line in `BladeCompiler.php` with:

   ```
   $contents = $this->compileString(ioncube_read_file($path));
   ```

   or (if you used a passphrase):

   ```
   $passphrase = "<my passphrase>";
   $contents = $this->compileString(ioncube_read_file($path, $is_encrypted, $passphrase));
   ```

   Please do note that you might want to make sure that the passphrase is secure within the file. You can find more information on these functions in the [User Guide](http://www.ioncube.com/sa/USER-GUIDE.pdf) on page 54.
2. To get `ioncube_read_file` working, you will need to encode the modified module. Furthermore, encode the rest of your application with the exception of  your Blade template files.
3. Encrypt (not encode!) your Blade template files, typically ending in `.blade.php`, and - if you use a passphrase - make sure it matches the one used for `ioncube_read_file`.

Please also keep in mind that this will generate standard PHP files from your encrypted ones, since the file is compiled and written back to the cache as plain text. If you want to change that it might be worth looking into the [User Guide](http://www.ioncube.com/sa/USER-GUIDE.pdf), p. 54 and override / extend the appropriate methods `bootstrap/compiled.php` such as `get` and `put` to detect if a file is encrypted, and to write an encrypted file if needed.

I should also mention, as this question is regularly asked on the ionCube HelpDesk: Despite all the encoding and encrypting, the HTML and JavaScript code *will* be displayed raw for all clients to see. I only mention this because it is a lot of effort to protect your Template files, which do consist in most cases mostly of HTML code. It does make any modification really hard (such as logo removal), but such things *may* also be achieved with some custom CSS.

Comment: Thanks for help, But when I search in Laravel to know where it read these blade templates by this function "file_get_contents" I didn't find.

Comment: @GoudaElalfy Extended the answer - can't test this myself, so please make sure to test thoroughly.

Comment: @sebih can you explain how you managed to encode your Laravel controllers? I'm having issues encoding mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846509/encoding-laravel-with-ioncube

Answer (score 3):

After coming across this issue I believe this answer will be the simple and easy way to solve it. With this methode you won't have to edit framework files every after update.

1. Create your own new Service Provider to replace ViewServiceProvider. Name it *IonCubeCompilerServiceProvider*
2. Create new Class to extend BladeCompiler. Name it *IonCubeBladeCompile*r
3. Finally, swap the ***Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class*** out of the config/app.php providers array, and replace it with your own ViewServiceProvider.

   ```
   namespace App\Providers;

   use App\Libraries\IonCubeBladeCompiler;
   use Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine;
   use Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider;

   class IonCubeCompilerServiceProvider extends ViewServiceProvider
   {
       public function registerBladeEngine($resolver)
       {
           $this->app->singleton('blade.compiler', function () {
               return new IonCubeBladeCompiler(
                   $this->app['files'], $this->app['config']['view.compiled']
               );
           });

           $resolver->register('blade', function () {
               return new CompilerEngine($this->app['blade.compiler']);
           });
       }
   }
   ```

Second file.

```
    namespace App\Libraries;


    use Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler;

    class IonCubeBladeCompiler extends BladeCompiler
    {
        public function compile($path = null)
        {
            if ($path) {
                $this->setPath($path);
            }

            if (! is_null($this->cachePath)) {
                if(function_exists('ioncube_read_file')){
                    //This is what I'm adding.
                    $contents = $this->compileString(ioncube_read_file($this->getPath()));
                }else{
                    //This is the original line.
                    $contents = $this->compileString($this->files->get($this->getPath()));
                }

                $this->files->put($this->getCompiledPath($this->getPath()), $contents);
            }
        }

    }
```

For more details you can check the following two links
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/extend-the-compile-function-on-bladecompilerphp 
and 
http://blog.ioncube.com/2016/12/19/ioncube-encoding-laravel-project-controllers-models-templates/

Comment: Excellent approach, leveraging framework features designed for enhancing behaviour.

Comment: I don't know why. But it's not working for me (Laravel 5.8.3)

Comment: eh...I think it is not related with Laravel version....but it is related with `ioncube_read_file()`.... the function doesn't decode my blade file... why??? for your information, i use IonCube 10.2

Comment: @SyamsoulAzrien have you use `--encrypt '*.blade.php'` in your ioncube command?

Answer (score 3):

I created class:

```
 <?php


namespace App\Classes\Compiler;


use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

use Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler;
use Illuminate\View\Compilers\CompilerInterface;


class CustomCompiler extends Compiler implements CompilerInterface
{
    /**
     * All of the registered extensions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $extensions = [];

    /**
     * All custom "directive" handlers.
     *
     * This was implemented as a more usable "extend" in 5.1.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $customDirectives = [];

    /**
     * The file currently being compiled.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $path;

    /**
     * All of the available compiler functions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $compilers = [
        'Extensions',
        'Statements',
        'Comments',
        'Echos',
    ];

    /**
     * Array of opening and closing tags for raw echos.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $rawTags = ['{!!', '!!}'];

    /**
     * Array of opening and closing tags for regular echos.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $contentTags = ['{{', '}}'];

    /**
     * Array of opening and closing tags for escaped echos.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $escapedTags = ['{{{', '}}}'];

    /**
     * The "regular" / legacy echo string format.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $echoFormat = 'e(%s)';

    /**
     * Array of footer lines to be added to template.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $footer = [];

    /**
     * Placeholder to temporary mark the position of verbatim blocks.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $verbatimPlaceholder = '@__verbatim__@';

    /**
     * Array to temporary store the verbatim blocks found in the template.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $verbatimBlocks = [];

    /**
     * Counter to keep track of nested forelse statements.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $forelseCounter = 0;

    /**
     * Compile the view at the given path.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @return void
     */
    public function compile($path = null)
    {
        if ($path) {
            $this->setPath($path);
        }

        if (! is_null($this->cachePath)) {
            if (function_exists('ioncube_read_file')) {
                $contents = $this->compileString(ioncube_read_file($this->getPath()));
            }
            else {
                $contents = $this->compileString($this->files->get($this->getPath()));
            }

            $this->files->put($this->getCompiledPath($this->getPath()), $contents);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the path currently being compiled.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * Set the path currently being compiled.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @return void
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    /**
     * Compile the given Blade template contents.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function compileString($value)
    {
        $result = '';

        if (strpos($value, '@verbatim') !== false) {
            $value = $this->storeVerbatimBlocks($value);
        }

        $this->footer = [];

        // Here we will loop through all of the tokens returned by the Zend lexer and
        // parse each one into the corresponding valid PHP. We will then have this
        // template as the correctly rendered PHP that can be rendered natively.
        foreach (token_get_all($value) as $token) {
            $result .= is_array($token) ? $this->parseToken($token) : $token;
        }

        if (! empty($this->verbatimBlocks)) {
            $result = $this->restoreVerbatimBlocks($result);
        }

        // If there are any footer lines that need to get added to a template we will
        // add them here at the end of the template. This gets used mainly for the
        // template inheritance via the extends keyword that should be appended.
        if (count($this->footer) > 0) {
            $result = ltrim($result, PHP_EOL)
                .PHP_EOL.implode(PHP_EOL, array_reverse($this->footer));
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Store the verbatim blocks and replace them with a temporary placeholder.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    protected function storeVerbatimBlocks($value)
    {
        return preg_replace_callback('/(?<!@)@verbatim(.*?)@endverbatim/s', function ($matches) {
            $this->verbatimBlocks[] = $matches[1];

            return $this->verbatimPlaceholder;
        }, $value);
    }

    /**
     * Replace the raw placeholders with the original code stored in the raw blocks.
     *
     * @param  string  $result
     * @return string
     */
    protected function restoreVerbatimBlocks($result)
    {
        $result = preg_replace_callback('/'.preg_quote($this->verbatimPlaceholder).'/', function () {
            return array_shift($this->verbatimBlocks);
        }, $result);

        $this->verbatimBlocks = [];

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Parse the tokens from the template.
     *
     * @param  array  $token
     * @return string
     */
    protected function parseToken($token)
    {
        list($id, $content) = $token;

        if ($id == T_INLINE_HTML) {
            foreach ($this->compilers as $type) {
                $content = $this->{"compile{$type}"}($content);
            }
        }

        return $content;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the user defined extensions.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileExtensions($value)
    {
        foreach ($this->extensions as $compiler) {
            $value = call_user_func($compiler, $value, $this);
        }

        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * Compile Blade comments into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileComments($value)
    {
        $pattern = sprintf('/%s--(.*?)--%s/s', $this->contentTags[0], $this->contentTags[1]);

        return preg_replace($pattern, '', $value);
    }

    /**
     * Compile Blade echos into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileEchos($value)
    {
        foreach ($this->getEchoMethods() as $method => $length) {
            $value = $this->$method($value);
        }

        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * Get the echo methods in the proper order for compilation.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getEchoMethods()
    {
        $methods = [
            'compileRawEchos' => strlen(stripcslashes($this->rawTags[0])),
            'compileEscapedEchos' => strlen(stripcslashes($this->escapedTags[0])),
            'compileRegularEchos' => strlen(stripcslashes($this->contentTags[0])),
        ];

        uksort($methods, function ($method1, $method2) use ($methods) {
            // Ensure the longest tags are processed first
            if ($methods[$method1] > $methods[$method2]) {
                return -1;
            }
            if ($methods[$method1] < $methods[$method2]) {
                return 1;
            }

            // Otherwise give preference to raw tags (assuming they've overridden)
            if ($method1 === 'compileRawEchos') {
                return -1;
            }
            if ($method2 === 'compileRawEchos') {
                return 1;
            }

            if ($method1 === 'compileEscapedEchos') {
                return -1;
            }
            if ($method2 === 'compileEscapedEchos') {
                return 1;
            }
        });

        return $methods;
    }

    /**
     * Compile Blade statements that start with "@".
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function compileStatements($value)
    {
        $callback = function ($match) {
            if (Str::contains($match[1], '@')) {
                $match[0] = isset($match[3]) ? $match[1].$match[3] : $match[1];
            } elseif (isset($this->customDirectives[$match[1]])) {
                $match[0] = $this->callCustomDirective($match[1], Arr::get($match, 3));
            } elseif (method_exists($this, $method = 'compile'.ucfirst($match[1]))) {
                $match[0] = $this->$method(Arr::get($match, 3));
            }

            return isset($match[3]) ? $match[0] : $match[0].$match[2];
        };

        return preg_replace_callback('/\B@(@?\w+(?:::\w+)?)([ \t]*)(\( ( (?>[^()]+) | (?3) )* \))?/x', $callback, $value);
    }

    /**
     * Compile the "raw" echo statements.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileRawEchos($value)
    {
        $pattern = sprintf('/(@)?%s\s*(.+?)\s*%s(\r?\n)?/s', $this->rawTags[0], $this->rawTags[1]);

        $callback = function ($matches) {
            $whitespace = empty($matches[3]) ? '' : $matches[3].$matches[3];

            return $matches[1] ? substr($matches[0], 1) : '<?php echo '.$this->compileEchoDefaults($matches[2]).'; ?>'.$whitespace;
        };

        return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $value);
    }

    /**
     * Compile the "regular" echo statements.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileRegularEchos($value)
    {
        $pattern = sprintf('/(@)?%s\s*(.+?)\s*%s(\r?\n)?/s', $this->contentTags[0], $this->contentTags[1]);

        $callback = function ($matches) {
            $whitespace = empty($matches[3]) ? '' : $matches[3].$matches[3];

            $wrapped = sprintf($this->echoFormat, $this->compileEchoDefaults($matches[2]));

            return $matches[1] ? substr($matches[0], 1) : '<?php echo '.$wrapped.'; ?>'.$whitespace;
        };

        return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $value);
    }

    /**
     * Compile the escaped echo statements.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileEscapedEchos($value)
    {
        $pattern = sprintf('/(@)?%s\s*(.+?)\s*%s(\r?\n)?/s', $this->escapedTags[0], $this->escapedTags[1]);

        $callback = function ($matches) {
            $whitespace = empty($matches[3]) ? '' : $matches[3].$matches[3];

            return $matches[1] ? $matches[0] : '<?php echo e('.$this->compileEchoDefaults($matches[2]).'); ?>'.$whitespace;
        };

        return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $value);
    }

    /**
     * Compile the default values for the echo statement.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function compileEchoDefaults($value)
    {
        return preg_replace('/^(?=\$)(.+?)(?:\s+or\s+)(.+?)$/s', 'isset($1) ? $1 : $2', $value);
    }

    /**
     * Compile the each statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileEach($expression)
    {
        return "<?php echo \$__env->renderEach{$expression}; ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the inject statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileInject($expression)
    {
        $segments = explode(',', preg_replace("/[\(\)\\\"\']/", '', $expression));

        return '<?php $'.trim($segments[0])." = app('".trim($segments[1])."'); ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the yield statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileYield($expression)
    {
        return "<?php echo \$__env->yieldContent{$expression}; ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the show statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileShow($expression)
    {
        return '<?php echo $__env->yieldSection(); ?>';
    }

    /**
     * Compile the section statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileSection($expression)
    {
        return "<?php \$__env->startSection{$expression}; ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the append statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileAppend($expression)
    {
        return '<?php $__env->appendSection(); ?>';
    }

    /**
     * Compile the end-section statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileEndsection($expression)
    {
        return '<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>';
    }

    /**
     * Compile the stop statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileStop($expression)
    {
        return '<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>';
    }

    /**
     * Compile the overwrite statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileOverwrite($expression)
    {
        return '<?php $__env->stopSection(true); ?>';
    }

    /**
     * Compile the unless statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileUnless($expression)
    {
        return "<?php if (! $expression): ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the end unless statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileEndunless($expression)
    {
        return '<?php endif; ?>';
    }

    /**
     * Compile the lang statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileLang($expression)
    {
        return "<?php echo app('translator')->get$expression; ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the choice statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileChoice($expression)
    {
        return "<?php echo app('translator')->choice$expression; ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the else statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileElse($expression)
    {
        return '<?php else: ?>';
    }

    /**
     * Compile the for statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileFor($expression)
    {
        return "<?php for{$expression}: ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the foreach statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileForeach($expression)
    {
        preg_match('/\( *(.*) +as *(.*)\)$/is', $expression, $matches);

        $iteratee = trim($matches[1]);

        $iteration = trim($matches[2]);

        $initLoop = "\$__currentLoopData = {$iteratee}; \$__env->addLoop(\$__currentLoopData);";

        $iterateLoop = '$__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getFirstLoop();';

        return "<?php {$initLoop} foreach(\$__currentLoopData as {$iteration}): {$iterateLoop} ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the break statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileBreak($expression)
    {
        return $expression ? "<?php if{$expression} break; ?>" : '<?php break; ?>';
    }

    /**
     * Compile the continue statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileContinue($expression)
    {
        return $expression ? "<?php if{$expression} continue; ?>" : '<?php continue; ?>';
    }

    /**
     * Compile the forelse statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileForelse($expression)
    {
        $empty = '$__empty_'.++$this->forelseCounter;

        preg_match('/\( *(.*) +as *(.*)\)$/is', $expression, $matches);

        $iteratee = trim($matches[1]);

        $iteration = trim($matches[2]);

        $initLoop = "\$__currentLoopData = {$iteratee}; \$__env->addLoop(\$__currentLoopData);";

        $iterateLoop = '$__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getFirstLoop();';

        return "<?php {$empty} = true; {$initLoop} foreach(\$__currentLoopData as {$iteration}): {$iterateLoop} {$empty} = false; ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the can statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileCan($expression)
    {
        return "<?php if (app('Illuminate\\Contracts\\Auth\\Access\\Gate')->check{$expression}): ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the else-can statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileElsecan($expression)
    {
        return "<?php elseif (app('Illuminate\\Contracts\\Auth\\Access\\Gate')->check{$expression}): ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the cannot statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileCannot($expression)
    {
        return "<?php if (app('Illuminate\\Contracts\\Auth\\Access\\Gate')->denies{$expression}): ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the else-can statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileElsecannot($expression)
    {
        return "<?php elseif (app('Illuminate\\Contracts\\Auth\\Access\\Gate')->denies{$expression}): ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the if statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileIf($expression)
    {
        return "<?php if{$expression}: ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the else-if statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileElseif($expression)
    {
        return "<?php elseif{$expression}: ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the forelse statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileEmpty($expression)
    {
        $empty = '$__empty_'.$this->forelseCounter--;

        return "<?php endforeach; \$__env->popLoop(); \$loop = \$__env->getFirstLoop(); if ({$empty}): ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the has section statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileHasSection($expression)
    {
        return "<?php if (! empty(trim(\$__env->yieldContent{$expression}))): ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the while statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileWhile($expression)
    {
        return "<?php while{$expression}: ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the end-while statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileEndwhile($expression)
    {
        return '<?php endwhile; ?>';
    }

    /**
     * Compile the end-for statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileEndfor($expression)
    {
        return '<?php endfor; ?>';
    }

    /**
     * Compile the end-for-each statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileEndforeach($expression)
    {
        return '<?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getFirstLoop(); ?>';
    }

    /**
     * Compile the end-can statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileEndcan($expression)
    {
        return '<?php endif; ?>';
    }

    /**
     * Compile the end-cannot statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileEndcannot($expression)
    {
        return '<?php endif; ?>';
    }

    /**
     * Compile the end-if statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileEndif($expression)
    {
        return '<?php endif; ?>';
    }

    /**
     * Compile the end-for-else statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileEndforelse($expression)
    {
        return '<?php endif; ?>';
    }

    /**
     * Compile the raw PHP statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compilePhp($expression)
    {
        return $expression ? "<?php {$expression}; ?>" : '<?php ';
    }

    /**
     * Compile end-php statement into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileEndphp($expression)
    {
        return ' ?>';
    }

    /**
     * Compile the unset statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileUnset($expression)
    {
        return "<?php unset{$expression}; ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the extends statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileExtends($expression)
    {
        $expression = $this->stripParentheses($expression);

        $data = "<?php echo \$__env->make($expression, array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>";

        $this->footer[] = $data;

        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Compile the include statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileInclude($expression)
    {
        $expression = $this->stripParentheses($expression);

        return "<?php echo \$__env->make($expression, array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the include statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileIncludeIf($expression)
    {
        $expression = $this->stripParentheses($expression);

        return "<?php if (\$__env->exists($expression)) echo \$__env->make($expression, array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the stack statements into the content.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileStack($expression)
    {
        return "<?php echo \$__env->yieldPushContent{$expression}; ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the push statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compilePush($expression)
    {
        return "<?php \$__env->startPush{$expression}; ?>";
    }

    /**
     * Compile the endpush statements into valid PHP.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    protected function compileEndpush($expression)
    {
        return '<?php $__env->stopPush(); ?>';
    }

    /**
     * Strip the parentheses from the given expression.
     *
     * @param  string  $expression
     * @return string
     */
    public function stripParentheses($expression)
    {
        if (Str::startsWith($expression, '(')) {
            $expression = substr($expression, 1, -1);
        }

        return $expression;
    }

    /**
     * Get the extensions used by the compiler.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getExtensions()
    {
        return $this->extensions;
    }

    /**
     * Register a custom Blade compiler.
     *
     * @param  callable  $compiler
     * @return void
     */
    public function extend(callable $compiler)
    {
        $this->extensions[] = $compiler;
    }

    /**
     * Call the given directive with the given value.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  string|null  $value
     * @return string
     */
    protected function callCustomDirective($name, $value)
    {
        if (Str::startsWith($value, '(') && Str::endsWith($value, ')')) {
            $value = Str::substr($value, 1, -1);
        }

        return call_user_func($this->customDirectives[$name], trim($value));
    }

    /**
     * Register a handler for custom directives.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  callable  $handler
     * @return void
     */
    public function directive($name, callable $handler)
    {
        $this->customDirectives[$name] = $handler;
    }

    /**
     * Get the list of custom directives.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCustomDirectives()
    {
        return $this->customDirectives;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the raw tags used by the compiler.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRawTags()
    {
        return $this->rawTags;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the raw tags used for the compiler.
     *
     * @param  string  $openTag
     * @param  string  $closeTag
     * @return void
     */
    public function setRawTags($openTag, $closeTag)
    {
        $this->rawTags = [preg_quote($openTag), preg_quote($closeTag)];
    }

    /**
     * Sets the content tags used for the compiler.
     *
     * @param  string  $openTag
     * @param  string  $closeTag
     * @param  bool    $escaped
     * @return void
     */
    public function setContentTags($openTag, $closeTag, $escaped = false)
    {
        $property = ($escaped === true) ? 'escapedTags' : 'contentTags';

        $this->{$property} = [preg_quote($openTag), preg_quote($closeTag)];
    }

    /**
     * Sets the escaped content tags used for the compiler.
     *
     * @param  string  $openTag
     * @param  string  $closeTag
     * @return void
     */
    public function setEscapedContentTags($openTag, $closeTag)
    {
        $this->setContentTags($openTag, $closeTag, true);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the content tags used for the compiler.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getContentTags()
    {
        return $this->getTags();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the escaped content tags used for the compiler.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEscapedContentTags()
    {
        return $this->getTags(true);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the tags used for the compiler.
     *
     * @param  bool  $escaped
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getTags($escaped = false)
    {
        $tags = $escaped ? $this->escapedTags : $this->contentTags;

        return array_map('stripcslashes', $tags);
    }

    /**
     * Set the echo format to be used by the compiler.
     *
     * @param  string  $format
     * @return void
     */
    public function setEchoFormat($format)
    {
        $this->echoFormat = $format;
    }
}
```

Then created provider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Classes\Compiler\CustomCompiler;
use Illuminate\View\Engines\CompilerEngine;
use Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider as ViewProvider;

class ViewServiceProvider extends ViewProvider
{
    public function registerBladeEngine($resolver)
    {
        $this->app->singleton('blade.compiler', function () {
            return new CustomCompiler(
                $this->app['files'], $this->app['config']['view.compiled']
            );
        });

        $resolver->register('blade', function () {
            return new CompilerEngine($this->app['blade.compiler']);
        });
    }

}
```

then replaced
`Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,`
with my own
`App\Providers\ViewServiceProvider::class,`
in config/app.php.
Then put the `.blade.php` to the Non-PHP-encryption extensions.
I use obfuscation and generated key.
Blade templates work fine.